# AWS ElasticSearch ESHttpPost to account "A" with ES cluster setup from lambda in account "B"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-opensearch

I have an AWS ElasticSearch Cluster in account "A".

I'm trying to create a lambda (triggered via API) in account "B" that will fetch data from ES in account "A".

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::AccountB:assumed-role/lambdaRole is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost because no resource-based policy allows the es:ESHttpPost action"
```

My Access policy in ES Security Configuration:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:AccountA:domain/domainName/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            List of IP Addresses
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I modified the access policy with the following but still facing the same issue:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:AccountA:domain/domainName/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:AccountA:domain/domainName/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            List Of Ip Addresses
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just to check. Would your lambda work perfectly fine if it was in the same account?

Comment: yes if its the same account its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratched my head a lot for this. Basically what is happening is that resource based policy only allows access to requests from same account. If it is a cross account access, we also need identity based policy from the originating account.
Take this for example

- ES cluster in account A
- Lambda function in account A
- Another lambda function in account B
- Domain access policy that allows access to lambdas on both accounts A & B
- Now, when we sign & make requests from lambda in account A, it will work even if the lambda **doesn't** have `es:ESHttp*` permissions
- But lambda B will not work this way. We also need to add `es:ESHttp*` permission to the role in lambda B.

This is because for same account access resource based policy is enough, but for cross-account access we also need a identity policy on the requesting service (lambda)

Here's the relevant documentation regarding this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic-cross-account.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly allow the role `arn:aws:sts::AccountB:assumed-role/lambdaRole` to perform all the actions on the Elasticsearch domain in `AccountA`.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:AccountA:domain/domainName/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "List of IP Addresses"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::AccountB:assumed-role/lambdaRole"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:AccountA:domain/domainName/*"
    }
  ]
}
```